# run script after due date

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a script to run after the due date is over once due date is over the query will update the status and expire the subscription but as of now I am getting a malfunction issue and the issue is that weh I run script it updates the status to expired I do not know as it should not run query

Here is my code

```
<?php
    if($user_data['subscription'] == 'Activated'):
        $sql_chk    = $this->db->get_where('payment_trans', array('user_id' => $user_data['id']));
        $date_payed = $sql_chk->row()->date_payed;
        $d_get      = new DateTime($date_payed);
        $d_get->modify('+1 year');
        $new_year   = $d_get->format('m-d-Y');
        $crnt_year  = time();

        if($crnt_year > strtotime($new_year)) {
            $data = array(
                'subscription' => 'Expired'
            );

            $this->db->where('id', $user_data['id']);
            $this->db->update('users', $data);
        }
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Don't convert dates to text to do maths.

Comment: You want create cron job script and set time

Comment: but when I am not converting then the logic is not working out for me

Comment: @Kheteshkumawat confused did not quite got you

Comment: for this you need to use cron job I'm agree with [@khetesh kumawat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6029549/khetesh-kumawat):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this .hope it helps

```
        $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if($user_data['subscription'] == 'Activated')
        {
            $sql_chk = $this->db->where('date_payed <', $current_date)->where('user_id', $user_data['id'])
                                 ->get('payment_trans');

            if ($sql_chk->num_rows() > 0) {
                $data = array(
                    'subscription' => 'Expired'
                );
                $this->db->where('id', $user_data['id']);
                $this->db->update('users', $data);
            }
        }
```